# Asserting equal length of string elements in a list

Tags: python, assertions

A function I created takes a **list of string** (long list of long sequences) as an argument. Initially, I want to make sure **all strings are of equal length**. Of course, I could do it by iterating over all sequences in a loop and checking the length. But I am wondering - is there any way to do it faster/more efficiently?

I've tried looking at the `unittest` module but I am not sure whether it would suit here. Alternatively, I was thinking about creating a list of len(string) of all strings using list comprehension and then checking whether or elements are the same. However, this seems like a lot of effort.

Comment: You can't do this in less than `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of your list, because you have to check every string (unless you have additional information you haven't mentioned). However, `len(string)` is `O(1)` in Python, so that's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot jonrsharpe. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [ ... ]
FIXED_SIZE = 100 # Lenght of each string which should be equal
result = all(len(my_string) == FIXED_SIZE for my_string in my_list)
```

Comment: *"I could do it by iterating over all sequences in a loop and checking the length. But I am wondering - is there any way to do it faster/more efficiently?"*

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. If all are same length output will be `True` otherwise `False`.

```
str_list = ['ilo', 'jak']
str_len = map(len,str_list)
all(each_len == str_len[0] for each_len in str_len)
```